# Comparison in 2 Tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Hellow Good Afternoon, I have created a visual representation of my 2 tables and here they are.

[image]

Before I ask my question I want to explain this both tables. The table `tbl_AdMastefile` is the Masterfile of my system which will be the basis of comparison from my `tbl_GMFormat`.

My `tbl_GMFormat` has 3 important columns and they are `Count Date,Gondola Type and No.Of Units` but all of them will be used.

Little story about this `tbl_GMFormat` : Everytime I will import an Excel file in my program and I will fetch those data.

How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Let me explain the Image above, I want to compare those data that is same on the following columns `Outlet Name and Gondola Type` If the data has no match then leave it blank or else compare them.

I hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as You explain in parallel question - [Combine two Data from 2 Tables using SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157841/combine-two-data-from-2-tables-using-sql?noredirect=1#comment302585_157841)

Your current database MS SQL Server, You can start from:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_ADMasterfile.QuartNo,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.SORG,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Ace_Code,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Outlet_Code,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Outlet_Name,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.RSM,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.KAS,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Gondola_Type,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.No_Of_Unit,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Rent_Unit,
    tbl_ADMasterfile.Monthly_Rental,
    tbl_GMFormat.Count_Date,
    tbl_GMFormat.Gondola_Type
    tbl_GMFormat.no_of_units
FROM
    tbl_ADMasterfile
FULL JOIN tbl_GMFormat 
     ON tbl_ADMasterfile.Outlet_Name = tbl_GMFormat.Outlet_Name
     AND tbl_ADMasterfile.Gondola_Type = tbl_GMFormat.Gondola_Type
```

then You can add GROUP BY conditions (with aggregate functions) if necessary, DISTINCT You do not need (at first look)

little more information about JOINs - http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_full.asp